# liferay build-service

Tags: service, ant, build, liferay

I encountered problem in Liferay. I want to create new service exactly the same service like the one that presented in the Liferay's developer documentation. However, after copy-pasting the XML to the portlet folder I try to build t using the command on my command prompt:

```
ant build-service
```

I get nothing. It only say on the console like this:

```
Buildfile: D:\Program\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1\portlets\NewPortlet-portlet\build.xml
build-service:
```

It stayed like that for so damn long, and still. I don't know what's the problem, is it because the Ant? I use the latest version of apache ant(currently: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.4 compiled on May 22 2012)
Is it because of configuration in the build.xml in the portlet folder?

Anybody encountered the same problem? or is it just me?

Comment: Are you using the `service.xml` as specified in this [link](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/service-build-5)? Are you running on Windows or Mac?
I didn't encounter any such problem neither any of my team-mates, for this example. We are also using the same Ant 1.8 on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Ant hanging during a build task is typically because there is a cluster config enabled in a properties file.

Remove/comment out the cluster configurations and that should clear the problem.